# Is $2^{\sqrt{x}} -x$ an increasing function for some interval $[k,\infty]$

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

It is not increasing in $[0,\infty]$.

How do I show that there exists $k$ where the function is increasing for $x \ge k$

The derivative of $2^{\sqrt{x}}-x$ is:

$$\frac{2^{\sqrt{x}-1}\log(2)}{\sqrt{x}}-1$$

I am stuck at understanding how to show that $\frac{2^{\sqrt{x}-1}\log(2)}{\sqrt{x}} > 1$

What would be the next step to prove this?

Is it enough to show that it is true for $x=4$ and then take the derivative and show that the derivative is greater than $0$.

I calculate the derivative at:

$$\frac{2^{\sqrt{x}-2}\log(2)(\sqrt{x}\log(2)-1)}{x^{3/2}}$$

Since $\sqrt{4}log(2) > 1$, it follows that this is positive for $x \ge 4$.

Is this enough to show that $2^{\sqrt{x}} -x$ is increasing?  Is there a simpler method?

---

Edit: In the original post, I did not specify the domain.  I have added domain since this is required for the question to be valid.

Comment: "*Is it enough to show that it is true for* $x=4$ *and then take the derivative and show that the derivative is greater than* $0$." Why at $x=4$? Per se, wouldn't this allow it to be negative for some $\beta<4$?

Comment: The function is *not* increasing on $[0,\infty)$: it is actually increasing, then decreasing, then increasing.

Comment: Yes, it is not increasing on $[0,\infty]$.  Is it increasing on $[16,\infty]$ or does it continue to increase, then decrease?  Thanks.

Comment: @LarryFreeman Please, edit your question to specify the domain. As it stands, as mentioned above what you are trying to prove is **not** true.

Comment: Thanks @Clement!  That's what I was looking for.  Appreciate it.  What did I do wrong in my reasoning?

Comment: @LarryFreeman Your argument is true as long as you specify a starting point for your interval, i.e. $[16,\infty]$. The same holds with the derivatives - your derivative is only greater than $1$ for $x > 25.762$

Comment: @LarryFreeman Otherwise: set $t=\sqrt{x}$. You want to show that for some value $t_0>0$, we have $\frac{2^{t-1}\ln 2}{t}>1$ for all $t\geq t_0$, or equivalently $$2^{t} - \frac{2t}{\ln 2} > 0.$$
Study the function $g(t) = 2^{t} - \frac{2t}{\ln 2}$. Its derivatives will be nicer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it's trivial that $2^u > u^2$ for all **sufficiently large** $u$. Take $\log_2$ on both sides to get
$$u > 2\log_2(u) \tag{1}$$
and the inequality is obvious.  To get your function into this form note that when $u=\sqrt{x}$
$$2^\sqrt{x} - x = 2^u - u^2$$
If you really want to use differentiation I would start with $(1)$ to get
$$f(u) = u-2\log_2(u)$$
$$f'(u) = 1-\frac{2}{\ln(2)u}\approx 1- 2.88u^{-1}$$
This function is clearly positive for sufficiently large $u$, and approaches $1$

Comment: Great argument.  How would I figure out the point at which it starts to increase?  As far as I can tell, it doesn't start to increase until $16$.  Am I wrong?  How do I fix my argument above?  Thanks.